# Three cafes,R S,and M take one step to go to one of these cafes to another. How many unique ways are there to start at R and end at M in seven steps?

Tags: combinatorics

There is an equilateral triangle with one cafe at each vertice. They are called R, S, and M.

I tried to solve this problem but got stuck. Here is my work:

After knowing that R and M are the endpoints, we can alternate to the 3 cafes for 5 steps or 6 times. I have two choices for each cafe. Hence, the answer is 2^6 or **64**.

After some testing and writing down some possibilities, I saw that this theory was wrong. I then tried to use casework to solve this problem. Here are my cases:

Case 1: **Visit Cafe M once**

For this, It is easy to see that there is 1 way to visit Cafe M once, making it the last cafe to visit on our list.

Case 2: **Visit Cafe M Twice**

For this case, we can do 7 choose 2 (Using the formula for distributing n items into r groups.) to find the number of ways to visit Cafe M twice, one being at the end. For this, we get 21.

Case 3: **Visit Cafe M thrice**

For this, I did 6 choose 2 ( using the formula), and found it to be 15.

Case 4: **Visit Cafe M four times**

For this, I found 10 ways according to the formula by doing 5 choose 2.

**Altogether, I got 53 as my answer.**

However, after checking my answer, it said I was wrong and 43 was the answer. Where did I go wrong?

**Thanks!**

Comment: The title says three cafes while the body says six.  Please make a clear statement of the problem.  How many are there?  Which are one step apart?  I am guessing that there are three at the corners of an equilateral triangle, and that at any point you can go to either of the other two cafes, but you never say that.  If you visit M only once, don't you have to alternate between the other two so there is only one way?

Comment: There is an equilateral triangle that has one cafe at each vertice. They are named R, S, and M.

Comment: You should edit the question to make it clear.  Comments can disappear and people shouldn't be left in the dark as they read the question.  You also didn't respond to my comment on Case 1.  If you only visit M once and end there, you must alternate between R and S until then, so there is only one way.

Comment: Using something choose something is completely the wrong approach.  Please explain why you are using it.  You want a recurrence relation linking the number of ways with $k$ steps ending at each place to the number of ways with $k+1$ steps.

Comment: I did this because I was counting how many ways to visit the cafes after setting a fixed place for Cafe M.

Comment: I edited my body text to be more clear. I also changed my case 1 because I understood what you meant by it. How is 43 the answer though?

Answer (score 0):

Let $S(n)$ be the number of ways to start at $R$, take $n$ steps, and end at $S$.  Define $R(n), M(n)$ similarly.  At each step you can go anywhere except where you are so the recurrences are
$$S(n)=R(n-1)+M(n-1)\\R(n)=S(n-1)+M(n-1)\\M(n)=R(n-1)+S(n-1)$$
By symmetry $S(n)=M(n)$ and the starting condition is $R(0)=1,S(0)=0,M(0)=0$.  A quick spreadsheet (copy the equations down) will give the answer.  All the values are $2^n/3$ rounded one way or the other so the total is $2^n$ as you have two choices at each step.

Comment: Are you saying that 64 is the answer? I also suggested a method that involved me saying that each step has 2 choices, making 64 the answer. I also said that this was wrong and that 43 was the answer. Please clarify if possible.

Comment: 128/3 equals 42 2/3. Rounding this gives me 43. However, how can you get a fractional number of paths in the first place?

Comment: The $R$ recurrence gives $2^n/3+2/3$ when $n$ is even and $2^n/3-2/3$ when $n$ is odd.  The others are $2^n/3 \pm 1/3$ with the sign chosen to make the answer whole and depending on the parity of $n$.  The sign for $R$ is opposite the signs for the other two